# Woo commerce star rating display only when greater than 1

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to use the star rating system within woocommerce and having a bit of an issue. Its displaying perfectly when theres a rating but I would like it not to show up if the there are no ratings and I have tried a few different options with none seeming to work.

The basic code I'm using to display it is:

```
<div class="star-rating">
<?php if ($average = $product->get_average_rating()) : ?>
<?php echo '<div class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__( 'Rated %s 
out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $average).'"><span style="width:'.( ( 
$average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" 
class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' 
).'</span></div>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Its displaying for both rated an unrated items right now and any help would be greatly appreciated on removing it when the rating doesn't exist.

Comment: `if there are no ratings `->means 0 or empty ?

Comment: Correct. I tried to add <1 but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: <1? what value is saved when there is no rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `no-ratings` means `0`, then do like below:-

```
<?php if ($average = $product->get_average_rating()) : ?>
        <?php if($average > 0);?>
        <div class="star-rating">
            <?php echo '<div class="star-rating" title="'.sprintf(__( 'Rated %s out of 5', 'woocommerce' ), $average).'"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>'; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```